# Laravel Model attribute returns 0

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

I have a `Report` Model with fillables `user_id`, `complainant_id`, `title`, `detail`. The table migration also has the same fields, and I have double checked that they are correct.

My problem is when I fetch the reports using `Report:all()` or any kind of way to fetch the reports. The `complainant_id` is always 0. But in the database, they actually contain values that are not 0.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you Provide us Model Code?

Comment: Please post Model, Migration and View codes.

Comment: I have added images for reference. Thankyou

Comment: @Rick add your model and sample data

Comment: Crap. I'm really sorry for wasting your time. I have just realized that I have previously inserted a data where complainant_id was still not migrated after almost an hour of thinking why it was like that. Thus resulting in 0 as default value. I will take down the question soon. I'm just light headed for not having sleep for almost 2 days.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  The issue was I made the string column the primary key.

```
protected $primaryKey = "column";
```

When you do this, Laravel casts the column to a int (making everything zero) unless you add this

```
protected $keyType = "string";
public $incrementing = false;
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys)

Comment:  What else can I say! I'd upvote you twice if I could lol

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see the correct value when using just "model:all()" but when fetching data converting to Array or json(model0->json_decode() or toArray()) for getting single value it returns "0"
and then i got to know about model builtin function "getAttributes()" it helped.Below is the Syntax to use.
(I hope this will be helpfull for someone...)

```
 model->getAttributes()['attribute'];
```